# Select Distinct Count for First Name, Last Name, DOB in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get Distinct Count of First Name, Last Name based on DOB. Assuming that Two persons 
can share same name but not DOB.

```
SELECT  COUNT((DISTINCT [First Name], [Last Name], [DOB])) AS TotalCount
FROM    MyTable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get this info like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(1) AS TotalCount
FROM    ( SELECT    [First Name] ,
                    [Last Name] ,
                    [DOB]
          FROM      MyTable
          GROUP BY  [First Name] ,
                    [Last Name] ,
                    [DOB]
        ) a
```

Comment: dave, is there any chance to help me in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292351/sql-count-distinct-query-issue-on-writing-for-pivot-table-format

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't this be as simple as

```
SELECT [First Name]
      ,[Last Name]
      ,[DOB]
      ,COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
FROM     MyTable
GROUP BY [First Name]
        ,[Last Name]
        ,[DOB]
```

Comment: Unless he's really wanting to know how many distinct firstname/lastname/dob combos he had. I read it your way at first, also, but looking at it again, the question is ambiguous :(

Comment: Yes, I read it the other way.  One of our answers should help him.

Comment: Yes, I need only Distinct Count based on First Name, Last with DOB

Answer (score 0):

I think this query could be sufficient to answer this question. It may not be optimal coz I'm just a newbie

```
select distinct concat([First Name],' ',[Last Name],' ',DOB) from Orders
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**